# NullPointerException when assigning string from ArrayList to Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with my code, because it throws `NullPointerException` when I try to assign string from `arraylist` to `array`.

```
 String[][] data = new String[idList.size()][];
 for(int i = 1; i<=idList.size(); i++) {
     data[i][0] = idList.get(i);
     data[i][1] = nameList.get(i);
     data[i][2] = hList.get(i);
     data[i][3] = sList.get(i);
     data[i][4] = fList.get(i);
     data[i][5] = mList.get(i);
     data[i][6] = osList.get(i);
     data[i][7] = tsList.get(i);
     data[i][8] = podList.get(i);
     data[i][9] = pacList.get(i);
 }
```

Can someone please tell me how do I fix that?

Comment: In your debugger you will be able to see that `data[0]` is `null`.  I suggest you initialise them.

Answer (score 1):

`data[i]` is `null`, since you initialized `data` to contain `idList.size()` `null` references of type `String[]`.

Change

```
String[][] data = new String[idList.size()][];
```

to

```
String[][] data = new String[idList.size()][10];
```

which will initialize `data` to contain `idList.size()` references to a `String` array of length 10 (`String[10]`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to define the array properly (in both dimensions )

replace this

```
new String[idList.size()][];
```

for something like

```
new String[idList.size()][10]; // you have 10 different lists there...
```

and iterate in the for loop with zero base...

## Example:

```
    String[][] data = new String[idList.size()][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++) {
        data[i][0] = idList.get(i);
        data[i][1] = idList.get(i);
        data[i][2] = idList.get(i);
        data[i][3] = idList.get(i);
    }
```